# How to export Ecoinvent 3.5 Database with brightway2 to GEXF file?

Tags: python, gephi, brightway

I would like to Export a brightway2 database to a gexf file to visualize it with Gephi, like here:
https://chris.mutel.org/visualizing-ecoinvent.html

When I try to Export it, I get a KeyError.

my code is:

```
import brightway2 as bw
from bw2io.export.gexf import DatabaseToGEXF
gephi = DatabaseToGEXF("ecoinvent 3.5 cutoff")
gephi.export()
```

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be more properly filed as a [bug report](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/faq.html#i-found-a-bug-what-now).

This bug was fixed in 0.7.6, released today via the normal channels. However, the previous visualization you linked to was built on the `categories` present in ecoinvent version 2. Version 3 no longer has these categories (though other similar metadata is possible). Moreover, the linked visualization required a lot of manual work (especially for the labelling).

So, creating a similar visualization for a recent ecoinvent is possible, but not easy :) My guess is you would have to write a custom `DatabaseToGEXF` subclass that will export the metadata you are interested in using for graph clustering/coloring/etc.